# What does it mean when my R^2 for my cross validation vary a lot?

Tags: python, cross-validation

My R^2 values for the cross validation vary from 0.174 to 0.967. What's the reason behind this major difference?

```
Degree-1 polynomial: R^2 for every fold: [0.87593726 0.17452837 0.58873146 0.96734281 0.95324541 0.91276834
 0.92310873 0.86275813 0.94933422 0.96215234]

Degree-1 polynomial: Average R^2 for all the folds: 0.816990706233325, STD: 0.2388768905829066
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment.

A low R^2 value for a fold indicates that there is something in the fold that is not represented well by the polynomial.

I would create a scatter plot of your low R^2 folds and see how much they vary from the polynomial. It could just be noise and you just need to reshuffle your folds, or your folds need to be a larger sample size.

Comment: Thank you. How to increase the sample size of folds?

Comment: No problem. You either need more data, or you can reduce the number of folds, like only having 5 folds compared to 10.

Comment: Thanks again. How does Python decides upon the number of observations in the testing and training datasets for every fold? Like how many observations go for training and how many observations go for testing in every fold?

Comment: Typically folds are divided evenly, so every fold within a set has the same number of samples. I am unsure how you are dividing in Python currently, but your testing folds should all have the same sample size.

Comment: I have a dataset of 100 observations, so I'll end up with 20 observations in each fold (assuming k=5). But the question is, let's say for the first fold, how does Python decide how much out of the 20 observations will go for training and how much will go for testing? Or is it also equal? 10 for training and 10 for testing? Or does it do it in a way that does not cause any repetition for the testing observations?

Comment: Ah, I see. individual folds are not split into training/testing. What ends up is that for the first fold, the entire fold is used for testing, and the other 4 folds are used for training (i.e. 20 observations used for testing and 80 used for training). So, when you cross-validate for each fold, you use that fold for testing and train with the other 4 folds.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!